# select user under certain criteria (if exists in the list)

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have property Users of type List;
I'm using List Exists method to check if this list contains object with equal property name with one passed as parameter.

```
public User SomeAction(User user)
{
   List<User> users = GetUsers();
   if(users.Exists(x => x.Name == user.Name))
   {
      // select user which exist under above criteria
   }
}
```

My question is
what statement to use to select user under above criteria?

Comment: What do you return if user not exists?

Comment: if user does not exist than I move to else statement for further processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be like this:

```
users.Where((x=>x.Name == user.Name).SingleOrDefault();
```

and in general can refactor your code to:

```
List<User> users = GetUsers();
var foundUser =  users.Where((x=>x.Name == user.Name).SingleOrDefault();
if(foundUser != null) {
  //DO SOMETHING AS THERE IS A USER
}
```

So avoid double query.

Note: here I assumed that `User` is a reference type, so it's default value is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Any Statement.. This will return true if the statement matches any objects.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx

```
if(users.Any(x=>x.Name == user.Name)){
  //....
}
```

EDIT: Missed the part requiring the user to select the user after checking if it exists. In the case where you want to select the first match for an expression.

```
var match = users.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name.Equals(user.Name));
if(match != null){
   //...TODO
}
```

Comment: OP states that he wants to select user after checking if user exists, so this is a worst solution - it requires **two** queries

Comment: Apologies.. Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
users.Single(x=>x.Name == user.Name)
```

A few other things try use `String.Equals` instead

```
users.Single(x=>String.Equals(x.Name, user.Name))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `FirstOrDefault` - it returns `null` if user matching your criteria not exists, otherwise it returns matching user:

```
users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name == user.Name)
```

Also you can use `SingleOrDefault` if there should be exactly one user which matches your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

```
User user = users.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name == user.Name)
if(user != null)...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use single, to get only one user and get exception if there is more than one user with same name

```
var user = users.Single(x=>x.Name==user.Name);
```